# Joint distribution of $(\bar{X},\bar{X^2})$?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, bivariate

I have found in this [Pdf](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/kulperger/SS3858/Handouts/DeltaMethod.pdf), theorem 2, that asymptotically:
$(\frac{\sum X_i}{N}, \frac{\sum X_i^{2}}{N})$ converges in distribution to a bivariate random variable with mean $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ and covariance matrix $A$. I don't know how to prove it using the multivariate CLT theorem? Hints are most apreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what the $X_i$ are and what assumptions you are making about them.

Comment: @whuber, I think that the only assumption here is that $X_i$'s are iid.

Comment: You will need more than that for the conclusion to hold.  At a minimum, that common distribution must have a finite fourth moment.

Comment: @whuber, my bad, it says on the document that the $X_i$'s has finite $4$-th moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: The proof is a straightforward calculation. Rewrite the quantity of interest
$$
\sqrt n(\hat\mu_{1,n} - \mu_1,\hat\mu_{2,n}-\mu_2)
$$
in the form
$$
\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^N{\bf X_i}\tag1
$$
where ${\bf X}_i$ is shorthand for the 2-vector $(X_i-\mu_1,X_i^2-\mu_2)$.
The summands ${\bf X}_i$ in (1) are iid with mean zero and finite covariance matrix, so the multivariate CLT applies immediately. It remains to verify the covariance matrix of the limiting distribution, which equals the covariance matrix of the generic summand $(X-\mu_1,X^2-\mu_2)$. A sample calculation:
$$\operatorname{Var}(X^2-\mu_2)\stackrel{(a)}=E[(X^2-\mu_2)^2]=E[X^4-2\mu_2X^2+\mu_2^2]=:\mu_4-\mu_2^2$$
where step (a) uses the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)$ when $E(Y)=0$.

Comment: Aren't there any conditions to verify, as has @whuber commented?

Comment: Why the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ in equation $(1)$?

Comment: @Nooob The $\frac1{\sqrt n}$ appears because there is a $\frac1n$ inside $\hat\mu_{1,n}$ and $\hat\mu_{2,n}$ . The conditions for the CLT are satisfied because the $X_i$ have a finite fourth moment.

Comment: I see now. Is this all what is needed to be done in order to show  that  joint asymptotic distribution is normal ?! I feel stupid.

Comment: @Nooob The calculation is straightforward once you see that the conditions for the CLT are satisfied. The key step is recognizing equation (1). But you have to get past the notation -- it isn't obvious how to get to (1) until you play around with what you've been given.